# Coating applied to plastic (polymer suitable for straws) to repel carbon dioxide to prevent "floating"

Tags: plastics, applied-chemistry

We are four students currently finalizing our last exam-project before our bachelor.

We confirmed our hypothesis that straws floating to the top of your drink is a "problem" from our survey.

Our question here would be: Is there any coating or similar scientific method that can be applied to any suitable plastic material, (for the use of consuming beverage) that can prevent the carbon dioxide from sticking to the plastic material, and thereby lifting it to the surface?